# vb.net, how to turn dataset to xml

Tags: vb.net

I want to take my dataset and convert it to an xml string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfes785w.aspx) method:

```
yourDataSet.WriteXml("foo.xml")
```

Or if you want to save it to a string:

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
Using writer = New StringWriter(sb)
    yourDataSet.WriteXml(writer)
    Dim xml As String = sb.ToString()
End Using
```